# SQLite regular table and table for fts

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts3, fts4

I have table **news (id, news_id, news_title)** and I creat FTS table:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE news_search USING fts4 (news_title, tokenize=porter);
```

I use trigger to keep table NEWS and news_search in sync:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS insert_news_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON news 
BEGIN 
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO news_search (news_title) VALUES (NEW.news_title);
END;
```

Question: how to use search? When I do MATCH in news_search table it returns me only records from this table, but I need *news_id* from **news** table. May be I should add *news_id* column to **news_search** table?

What is the proper way to use fts in sqlite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_3); FTS tables also have a `rowid` column (also called `docid`) that you can set explicitly to the same value as the corresponding key of the original table.

Assuming that `news.id` is the `rowid` (i.e., INTEGER PRIMARY KEY), you should change your trigger to also copy that ID value into the `news_search` table.
You can the use that to look up the original record:

```
SELECT *
FROM news
WHERE id IN (SELECT docid
             FROM news_search
             WHERE news_title MATCH '')
```